# Where can I get census data containing details about each person of a particular village in India?

Tags: india, data-sources, census

I am doing research on a project. And for that, I need details like- age, jobs, income, etc. of all persons of a particular village in India. I have already searched for census data , but I got only brief descriptions of village in numbers, that include, total population, no. of children, literacy rate and so on.. But I need details about each person.

Comment: Welcome! This might be a better question for [opendata.se].

Comment: Is that information publicly available?

Comment: I am ~100% sure that data is not publicly available. Isn't providing that publicly would be dangerous to privacy of individuals ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully, you really really can't. While India isn't a signature to any convention like GDPR it is a party to a number of other international declarations that recognize the right to privacy.

[Specifically](https://www.linklaters.com/en/insights/data-protected/data-protected---india);

> India has also not yet enacted specific legislation on data protection. However, the Indian legislature did amend the Information Technology Act (2000) (“IT Act”) to include Section 43A and Section 72A, which give a right to compensation for improper disclosure of personal information.

Under the EUs GDPR [regulations](https://www.itgovernance.eu/blog/en/the-gdpr-what-exactly-is-personal-data) there are definitions for personal and identifiable data.

> “‘[P]ersonal data’ means any information relating to an identified or identifiable natural person (‘data subject’).”
>
> In other words, any information that is clearly about a particular person. But just how broadly does this apply? The GDPR clarifies:
>
> “[A]n identifiable natural person is one who can be identified, directly or indirectly, in particular by reference to an identifier such as a name, an identification number, location data, an online identifier or to one or more factors specific to the physical, physiological, genetic, mental, economic, cultural or social identity of that natural person.”

The level of detail you're asking for would make it relatively trivial to assign anonymous data back to individuals, breaching their data privacy.

Comment: Thank you for precise and elaborating response. But at some extent, I can get these details like dob, job, education and his/her interests from social networking sites. As people usually use to give these types of details. But it requires very hard work, that why i thought of getting census data a easy way.

Comment: @abhishek A government usually has a higher duty of care with official data, than a social media organisation has with data users choose to share. Though this may change after the issues surrounding Cambridge Analytica.

Comment: The GDPR is irrelevant here (nor is it a "convention" with "signatories").  Mentioning its substantive provisions is just confusing.